# Compiling unison for Windows 64 bit

Tags: compiler-errors, ocaml, unison

I followed the instructions to compile 64 bit Unison using the MSYS2 toolchain as outlined [HERE](https://www.onwebsecurity.com/windows/its-about-the-journey-compiling-64-bit-unison-gtk2-on-windows).

Briefly, here are the steps:

```
pacman -Sy --noconfirm base-devel git mingw-w64-x86_64-{glib2,gtk2,ocaml,toolchain}
sed -i "s/#include <gdk\/win32\/gdkwin32keys.h>/\/\/#include <gdk\/win32\/gdkwin32keys.h>/" /mingw64/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkwin32.h
VERSION=2.18.5 && pushd /tmp && wget -c https://forge.ocamlcore.org/frs/download.php/1627/$VERSION.tar.gz
tar -xzvf $VERSION.tar.gz && cd lablgtk-$VERSION && ./configure --prefix=/mingw64 --disable-gtktest && make ; strip src/dlllablgtk2.dll && make opt && make old-install INSTALLDIR=/mingw64/lib/ocaml/lablgtk2/ BINDIR=/mingw64/bin/ DLLDIR=/mingw64/lib/ocaml/stublibs/
pushd /tmp && git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison && cd unison
make windres && make src OSARCH=win32gnuc
```

The compile ended prematurely with the error:

```
ocamlopt: lwt/lwt_unix_stubs.c ---> lwt/lwt_unix_stubs.o
ocamlopt -g -I lwt -I ubase -I system -I fsmonitor -I fsmonitor/linux -I fsmonitor/windows -I system/win -I lwt/win -ccopt "-o "./lwt/lwt_unix_stubs.o -c ./lwt/lwt_unix_stubs.c
In file included from ./lwt/lwt_unix_stubs.c:8:0:
./lwt/lwt_unix_stubs.c: In function 'invoke_completion_callback':
C:\MSYS64\mingw64\lib\ocaml/caml/memory.h:236:12: error: 'caml__frame' undeclared (first use in this function)
     (void) caml__frame, \
            ^
C:\MSYS64\mingw64\lib\ocaml/caml/memory.h:236:12: note: in definition of macro 'CAMLxparam2'
     (void) caml__frame, \
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
./lwt/lwt_unix_stubs.c:82:3: note: in expansion of macro 'CAMLlocal2'
   CAMLlocal2 (err, name);
   ^
C:\MSYS64\mingw64\lib\ocaml/caml/memory.h:236:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
     (void) caml__frame, \
            ^
C:\MSYS64\mingw64\lib\ocaml/caml/memory.h:236:12: note: in definition of macro 'CAMLxparam2'
     (void) caml__frame, \
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
./lwt/lwt_unix_stubs.c:82:3: note: in expansion of macro 'CAMLlocal2'
   CAMLlocal2 (err, name);
   ^
make[1]: *** [Makefile.OCaml:434: lwt/lwt_unix_stubs.o] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/unison/src'
make: *** [Makefile:14: src] Error 2
```

Not too sure what is wrong, any help?

Comment: The `sed` command looks pretty suspicious to me. It comments out the line including a 32-bit library. This is a (very) long shot, but maybe the 64-bit counterpart is not included, leading to missing symbols?

Comment: The reasons are detailed in the post. It has got to do with incorrect referencing of labgtk. The compilation stops even if I do not compile the gtk GUI by specifying UISTYLE=text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here the original poster from the article...

I finally managed to reproduce the issue with OCaml - The current version of Unison doesn't strictly follow the OCaml interface guidelines, which can be found at http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.04/intfc.html

The relevant text: "In particular, CAMLlocal and CAMLxparam can only be called after CAMLparam". Therefore, a simple call to `CAMLparam(0)` fixes the issue:

```
--- a/src/lwt/lwt_unix_stubs.c
+++ b/src/lwt/lwt_unix_stubs.c
@@ -79,6 +79,7 @@

static void invoke_completion_callback
(long id, long len, long errCode, long action) {
+  CAMLparam0();
   CAMLlocal2 (err, name);
   value args[4];
   err = Val_long(0);
```

I updated the article at https://www.onwebsecurity.com/configuration/its-about-the-journey-compiling-64-bit-unison-gtk2-on-windows.html to include this patch, and will send it upstream to the Unison maintainers.

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm it works similarly on my setup.